# SpringMvc custom binding result break date format

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am practicing validating form with spring mvc binding result, when i validating the form, i got a result like this:

[image]

But i don't want the field name to just pop 2 error, i want it to pop error one at a time to an order i want, so i custom my bindingResult, here is the code:

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"create"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes ra, @ModelAttribute("product") @Valid Product product, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            var errors = customErrorMessageOrder(bindingResult.getFieldErrors());
            bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(product, "product");
            for(var e : errors) {
                bindingResult.addError(e);
            }
            modelMap.put("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.product", bindingResult);
            
            modelMap.put("categories", categoryService.findAll());
            return "admin/product/create";
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/product/index";
    }
    
    private List<FieldError> customErrorMessageOrder(List<FieldError> listErrors){
        var notEmptyListErrors = listErrors
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(e -> e.getCode().equals("NotEmpty") || e.getCode().equals("password.notEmpty"))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());  
        if(notEmptyListErrors.size()==0) {
            return listErrors;
        }
        
        var alterListErrors = listErrors.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        for(var e : notEmptyListErrors) {
            alterListErrors.removeIf(e1->e1.getField().equals(e.getField()));
        }
        
        notEmptyListErrors.addAll(alterListErrors);
        
        return notEmptyListErrors;
    }
```

Everything work as i expect, but there is 1 minor problem, when i test the validation again, the ***created*** field some how became like this:

[image]

I have already put ***@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")*** in my ***created*** field of the ***Product*** model, and if i remove the custom ***bindingResult*** part:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"create"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes ra, @ModelAttribute("product") @Valid Product product, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelMap.put("categories", categoryService.findAll());
            return "admin/product/create";
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/product/index";
    }
```

The ***created*** field's format is back to normal, so it must have something to do with my custom ***bindingResult***, but i don't know where is the problem and how to fix it, please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with you replacing the `bindingResult` parameter with a new instance. For troubleshooting, I'd try either looking at the Spring source code or logging the elements of `bindingResult` that *aren't* the two "notEmpty" cases you're looking for. Maybe there are others you need to add back to the new instance unchanged, to keep the default behavior.